# Since Win 10 1709 upgrade, Snipping tool 'Send Snip' does not work

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, mailto, windows-10-v1709, snipping

Since upgrading to Windows 10 1709, the snipping tool 'send snip' button does not work. Instead of opening Outlook 2016, it give me an error message of '*The snip could not be sent. Check that an email program is installed and then try again.*' Outlook 2016 is the default mail app and the app selected for the mailto protocol. HTML mailto links and the Email button in the Word 2016 Quick Access toolbar work as expected.

[image]

Comment: So far in my environment, 10 machines needs the fix while 3 did not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Windows 10 1709 Snipping Mail Problem](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e22f39d8-aa7d-431d-9749-ec03532078fc/windows-10-1709-snipping-mail-problem?forum=w7itprogeneral)

> 1. Click Start, and then click Run.
> 2. In the Open box, type regedit, and then press ENTER.
> 3. In Registry Editor, locate the following subkey in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\Mail\Microsoft Outlook
```

> 4. Select the subkey, create a backup (export), and then press DELETE.
> 5. Click Yes.
> 6. Quit Registry Editor.
> 7. Go to control panel – programs and features
> 8. Run repair of the office – the key will be recreated

See also [Snipping Tool Error "The snip could not be sent" Sending Snip to Email](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/snipping-tool-error-snip-not-sent-sending-snip-email/)

Comment: I have a feeling this question is going to get a lot of traction. All of the machines that I touch at work all are exhibiting this same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Problem : User were having issue not able to send any file attachment in their email. It used to do it but not lately.

Solution: Since we did an updated windows 10 1709, MS Office also came out a security update for outlook that causing this issue. In able to fix this issue, you will need to uninstall **KB4011626** update and take it out of WSUS and reboot client machine. This will fixed the issue.

Answer (score -2):

1. Close Outlook
2. Navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\system\MSMAPI\1033"
3. Delete "Msmapi32.dll"
4. Open Outlook (the DLL is recreated)